# How to adjust bootstrap's navbar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I'm trying to understand the navbar, I tried putting a background image to the navbar setting an ID to it:

HTML:

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tutorial</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#myNavbar{
        background-image:url(../images/image1.png); 
        background-size:cover;  
    }
```

what I am wondering is if there's a way to resize the height of the navbar according to the size of image1.png...

The image has an initial size of 1280x150 px and ends up being 400x50, and I want the bar to have the same sizes, because as it is right now, it starts on 1280x50 and ends up in 400x50, which crops the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding..are you asking for the navbar to be `400px` tall or `1280px` tall?

Get rid of your mention of the #myNavbar ID altogether and try this:

```
.navbar-default
{
    background-image:url(../images/image1.png); 
    background-size:cover;  
    height:150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){

  .navbar-default
     {
       background-image:url(../images/image1.png); 
       background-size:cover;  
       height:50px;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I want is that when it's a large screen the navbar has 150px tall and 1280px of width,  but when its a small device (mobile) the navbar should be 50px tall and 400 of width

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that Bootstrap already has it built in such that the width is 100% regardless of you resizing the screen.